# Java program slow down by printing line

Tags: java, inputstream

Hi I have a script that downloads are file from the web and while doing so prints out the progress. The problem is that the line that prints out the progress slows the program down alot, is there any way to stop this?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;


public class download {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        URL u = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast,_Dhaka,_Bangladesh.JPG");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://Users/xxx/Desktop/test.jpg");
        InputStream is = u.openStream();

        long size = u.openConnection().getContentLengthLong();
        int data;
        long done = 0;
        while((data = is.read())!=-1){
            double progress = (double) (done)/(double)(size)*100;
            System.out.println(progress); // if we dont do this then then it completes fast
            fos.write(data);
            done++;
        }
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try only printing out every xth loop.

```
if(done % 10 == 0) System.out.println(progress);
```

Comment: Is this the only way? I thought I might be able to use threads to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm sure there are others but threads to show progress in a console app is probably overkill

Comment: K.I.S.S  until it needs to be less S

Comment: @user550 using a thread won't solve anything because they will write into the same disk.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I disagree. It is simple but inefficient. I believe your answer is the correct solution although my answer answers the question directly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, every I/O operation takes a high cost. Now, you're printing a message **for every byte read!** (noted in [InputStream#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29)).

If you want/need to print the progress, do it for a bunch of KBs read, usually every 4 KBs. You can do this by using a `byte[] buffer` to read and write the data from the streams.

```
BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutStream output = null;
final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;
try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(is, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        done += length;
        double progress = (double) (done)/(double)(size)*100
        System.out.println(progress);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //log your exceptions...
} finally {
    closeResource(output);
    closeResource(input);
}
```

And have this `closeResource` method:

```
public void closeResource(Closeable resource) {
    if (resource != null) {
        try {
            resource.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while closing the resource.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to close at least `output` in case there is no exception or you're not guaranteed that your file is complete.

Comment: @zapl my code was incomplete and misleading. Updated the answer.

Comment: @user550 I believe that this is the correct answer. My answer solved your symptom but this one cures your problem.

Comment: There is still a slight problem, if you ignore closing errors while writing you might miss errors happening during the final flush that happens during that time :) (I usually put an additional close for writers within the try block so errors there are handled with other exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

You can print the line only if `(done % 100 == 0)` let's say.

Also, you can use buffered way of reading, that would speed the program up.

Comment: Perhaps name the class? BufferedReader

Comment: @SimonTrewhella OP can keep the same class but use a different method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: don't print the progress with every iteration of the loop. Use a counter, decide on a reasonable frequency, a number to mod the counter by, and print the progress at that selected frequency.